# Como faço para desativar essa notificação? "Based on your project, we have identified extensions you may find helpful"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

[image: Notificação do mal!]

Não tenho ideia do porquê disso ter começado a aparecer, imagino que foi depois uma atualização do Visual Studio, mas ela me irrita, e continua aparecendo mesmo depois de clicar no "Dont' Show Again". Como faço para sumir de vez com essa coisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um probleminha "chato" que aparece no Visual Studio Community 2015.

Você pode ver a discussão [nesse issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/305) .

Para resolver o problema, basta seguir esses passos:

> "A questão é que um ajuste não está sendo mantida. A solução é alterar manualmente a configuração. Vá para  Tools->Options->Text Editors->HTML->Advanced e certifique-se de que Identify Helpful Extensions está definida como false. (Nota , será "false" se você já descartou a barra amarela na sessão atual VS. neste caso, apenas a ação de mostrar a caixa de diálogo opções e fechando-o com "OK" será suficiente para persistir o ajuste). "

[Fonte MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/4bc107df-0f0f-4b05-bc8e-e84dc75e2f2c/visual-studio-2015-community-based-on-your-project-we-have-identified-extensions-you-might-find?forum=visualstudiogeneral#acd36b64-0b22-4980-beab-9b3b7252b860)